# Add a checkbox to a JTable which has been generated from a CSV

Tags: java, csv, checkbox, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I have a function which loops through a CSV file, and generates a DefaultTableModel of the data (which is then displayed in a JTable). This function is:

```
public DefaultTableModel createTableModel(Reader in, Vector<Object> headers) {
        DefaultTableModel model = null;
        Scanner s = null;
        Vector<Object> c;
        try {
            Vector<Vector<Object>> rows = new Vector<Vector<Object>>();
            s = new Scanner(in);
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                rows.add(new Vector<Object>(
                        Arrays.asList(s.nextLine().split("\\s*,\\s*", -1))));
            }
            if (headers == null) {
                headers = rows.remove(0);
                model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, headers);
            } else {
                model = new DefaultTableModel(rows, headers);
            }
            return model;
        } finally {
            s.close();
        }
    }
```

However, I would like to modify this code to add a checkbox to the first column of data (which I have added as a template when generating the CSV file anyways as a column with header "Selected"), which fills in the boolean `false` for each row.

The problem is, I don't know where in my code something like the below should go (after reading online I see that this is the way you can get a JTable to autogenerate selection textboxes, by setting the class of a column to `Boolean`). Note, here the "Selected" column is column 1 hard coded:

```
{
    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
         if(column==1){
                        return Boolean.class;
         }else return String.class;
      }
 };
```

Should be defined (I am presuming it should be in the function above).

Comment: btw, [the ``Vector`` class is obsolete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing a function that creates a DefaultTableModel, you could subclass DefaultTableModel and add override the functions that you need..

If you want the first column, it should be 0, not 1. And you will probably also need to override the getValueAt() in order to actually return a boolean.